# WebFluxConfigurer broken in Spring webflux for functional routes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, webflux

The goal is to configure my webflux servlet container such that whenever an API call is made to a predefined path will return a response regardless of whether the call is made to an upper/lower case path.

**/api/users**   should give the same result as **/api/USERS**

This functional route definition along with the WebFluxConfigurer below does not appear to settle it.

```
@Configuration
class UserRoutes {

    @Bean
    fun userRouterFunction(
        userHandler: userHandler
    ) = coRouter {
        "/users".nest {
            GET("/all", userHandler::getAllUser)
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
class WebConfig : WebFluxConfigurer {

    override fun configurePathMatching(configurer: PathMatchConfigurer) {
        configurer.setUseCaseSensitiveMatch(false)
    }
}
```

Is anything amiss here?

Answer (score 1):

`@Configuration` classes must not be `final`. Change its access modifier to `open`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
open class WebConfig : WebFluxConfigurer {
    override fun configurePathMatching(configurer: PathMatchConfigurer) {
        configurer.setUseCaseSensitiveMatch(false)
    }
}
```

This works. I just tested.

Comment: The @Configuration annotation modifies the class to open by default. On a different note, I think the problem is with the functional definition of paths where I use CoRouterFunctionDsl. Am I to assume that the WebFluxConfigurer interface will not work for those paths?